# Explain this Function

Tags: c, comparison, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can someone explain to me the reason why someone would want use bitwise comparison?
example:

```
int f(int x) {
return x & (x-1); 
}
int main(){
  printf("F(10) = %d", f(10));
}
```

This is what I really want to know: "Why check for common set bits"

x is any positive number.

Comment: Where is the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ur-example is "testing if a number is even or odd":

```
unsigned int number = ...;
bool isOdd = (0 != (number & 1));
```

More complex uses include bitmasks (multiple boolean values in a single integer, each one taking up one bit of space) and encryption/hashing (which frequently involve bit shifting, XOR, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise operations are used for three reasons:

- You can use the least possible space to store information
- You can compare/modify an entire register (e.g. 32, 64, or 128 bits depending on your processor) in a single CPU instruction, usually taking a single clock cycle. That means you can do a lot of work (of certain types) *blindingly* fast compared to regular arithmetic.
- It's cool, fun and interesting. Programmers like these things, and they can often be the differentiator when there is no difference between techniques in terms of efficiency/performance.

You can use this for all kinds of very handy things. For example, in my database I can store a lot of true/false information about my customers in a tiny space (a single byte can store 8 different true/false facts) and then use '&' operations to query their status:

- Is my customer Male and Single and a Smoker?

  `if (customerFlags & (maleFlag | singleFlag | smokerFlag) ==`
  `(maleFlag | singleFlag | smokerFlag))`
- Is my customer (any combination of) Male Or Single Or a Smoker?

  `if (customerFlags & (maleFlag | singleFlag | smokerFlag) != 0)`
- Is my customer not Male and not Single and not a Smoker)?

  `if (customerFlags & (maleFlag | singleFlag | smokerFlag) == 0)`

Aside from just "checking for common bits", you can also do:

- Certain arithmetic, e.g. `value & 15` is a much faster equivalent of `value % 16`. This only works for certain numbers, but if you can use it, it can be a great optimisation.
- Data packing/unpacking. e.g. a colour is often expressed as a 32-bit integer that contains Alpha, Red, Green and Blue byte values. The Red value might be extracted with an expression like `red = (value >> 16) & 255;` (shift the value down 16 bit positions and then carve off the bottom byte)

  - Data manipulation and swizzling. Some clever tricks can be achieved with bitwise operations. For example, swapping two integer values without needing to use a third temporary variable, or converting ARGB colour values into another format (e.g RGBA or BGRA)

Comment: Re "Certain arithmetic, e.g. value & 15 is a much faster equivalent of value % 16.", I thought these ops would take the same amount of time on modern PCs. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Division (and modulus) still take more cycles than bit manipulation. However, modern *compilers* are usually smart enough to change the operator where possible (which is actually not as often as you think--for example, `n % 2` and `n & 1` give *different* answers if `n` is negative.)

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given is kinda odd, but I'll use bitwise comparisons all the time in embedded code.

I'll often have code that looks like the following:

```
volatile uint32_t *flags = 0x000A000;
bool flagA = *flags & 0x1;
bool flagB = *flags & 0x2;
bool flagC = *flags & 0x4;
```

Comment: Can you explain your example some?

Comment: There's not a whole lot to explain; it checks for bits 0, 1, and 2 (flags A, B, and C respectively) being "on" (high). Could be reading from jumpers, say.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bitwise *comparison*. It doesn't return a boolean.

Bitwise operators are used to read and modify individual bits of a number.

```
n &   0x8   // Peek at bit3
n |=  0x8   // Set bit3
n &= ~0x8   // Clear bit3
n ^=  0x8   // Toggle bit3
```

Bits are used in order to save space. 8 chars takes a lot more memory than 8 bits in a char.

The following example gets the range of an IP subnet using given an IP address of the subnet and the subnet mask of the subnet.

```
uint32_t mask = (((255 << 8) | 255) << 8) | 255) << 8) | 255;
uint32_t ip   = (((192 << 8) | 168) << 8) |   3) << 8) |   4;

uint32_t first = ip & mask;
uint32_t last  = ip | ~mask;
```

Comment: To be fair, nothing in C returns a boolean.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Your claim that the comparison operators don't return a boolean value is ludicrous. They return either a true value or a false value. That's not the case for the arithmetic operators and bitwise operators. They have many many different possible values, so they aren't boolean (only two possible values).

Comment: @ikegami: In C, boolean operations return an `int`, not a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. if you have a number of status flags in order to save space you may want to put each flag as a bit.

so x, if declared as a byte, would have 8 flags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean bitwise combination (in your case a bitwise AND operation).  This is a very common operation in those cases where the byte, word or dword value is handled as a collection of bits, eg status information, eg in SCADA or control programs.

Answer (score 0):

Your example tests whether x has at most 1 bit set. `f` returns 0 if x is a power of 2 and non-zero if it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Your particular example tests if two consecutive bits in the binary representation are `1`.

Comment: but why would someone want to do at?

Comment: No, it tests if `x` and `x*3` have any common set bits, which is not at all the same thing

Comment: @ChrisDodd thats what my question is why check common set bits.

Comment: @John Riselvato, Maybe each bit represents a signal from outside the machine, and you want to check if two nearby signals are one. Maybe that indicates a fault in some device. It really depends on what `x` is.

Comment: @John Riselvato, Maybe you are trying to perform some kind compression, and two adjancent set bits indicates an opportunity for compression. It really depends on what `x` is.

Comment: @ikegami what if x is any positive numeric value.

Comment: @John Riselvato, is simply a compact version of (flag1 && flag2) || (flag2 && flag3) || (flag3 && flag4) etc.

Comment: @John Riselvato, A number is not just a number. A number represents something. `x` isn't a number, `x` is something represented as a number.

Comment: @ikegami `int f(int x); return x & (x-2); int main(){ print f(6); }` what if thats my function

Comment: @John Riselvato, You already know what it does at a numerical level. Unless you say what the number means, we can't tell you what it does at the conceptual level, and that's what you're asking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3674/discussion-between-ikegami-and-john-riselvato)

Comment: @ikegami i get what its doing. taking `6 = 110` and `6-2 = 4 = 100` and outputs `4 = 100` because 110 & 100 = 100. I just want to know why this is useful.